# How to put tasks back to the ThreadPoolExecutor BlockingQueue?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice, executor

I'm developing a service which would pars large files simultaneously. I want to use `ThreadPoolExecutor` for my purposes, but problem is that by default `ThreadPoolExecutor` keep incoming tasks in `BlockingQueue` if all threads are busy.

Imagine the situation when we have 10 files 10gb each and 5 threads for performing 10 file parsing tasks, I want each thread:

1. Take task from queue.
2. Perform some amount of work(process 1gb of the hole file).
3. Suspend the task and put back into queue.
4. Take another task and repeat until all files would be processed.

Comment: Just curious, but why not just have the task process the complete file and then not have to worry about re-submission.

Comment: @Slaw Because I have client for each task and they dont want to wait untill other tasks would be performed cause process could take up to month, they want to monitor a real time statistics.

Comment: Is is possible to create all the tasks ahead-of-time, configuring each one to only process a specific portion of a certain file? Then you could interleave the tasks in the queue in order to "rotate" which files are being processed.

Comment: @Slaw no, cause users import those files to us via ftp before process starts.

Comment: Could you use a `ForkJoinPool` and break up your tasks into `ForkJoinTask`s? When a task is done processing a chunk, fork a new task for the next chunk and let the first task complete.

Comment: If only Java had a normal thread pool + async/await.. Java developers' lives would be so much simpler..

Comment: @Eric I suppose no, cause each task process large file in produser thread, put to consumer's thread buffer and consumer inserts to postgres DB. Plus, i dont think that it would work if there already 5 tasks running for the month and new task apears with new file. Plus files could be with different structure.

Comment: @DavidHaim is there an open source library which provides  thread pool + async/await, maybe you know?

Comment: Sounds like what you really need is some batch processing framework like Spring Batch.

Comment: @Eric no one would give me approve to rewrite the legacy architecture right now:(

Answer (score 2):

It may be possible to do using plain Java, but it depends on whether a task can checkpoint itself.  Here's a sketch:

```
Executor ex = ...

public class MyTask implements Runnable {
    private int next;  // The state of the computation 
    private int end;  //

    public MyTask(int start, int end) {
        this.next = start;
        this.end = end;

    public void run() {
        for (int i = next; i < end; i++) {
            // do stuff
            if (/* suspend task *) {
                this.next = i + 1;  // checkpoint task state
                executor.execute(this); // requeue this task
                return;  // release worker thread
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Finished task");
    }
}

for (...) {
    executor.execute(new MyTask(...));
}
```

Note that suspending the task consists of recording the current state of the computation in the fields of `this`, adding `this` to the queue, and then returning to release the worker thread.  When a suspended task reaches the head of the queue again, the executor will assign it to a worker thread, and the thread will call `run()` which will (must) resume the computation from the checkpoint.